# How to tell if a user has selected text on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know if someone has selected text on my page so I can display a context menu right where their cursor is. But I only want to display it if they have selected text by double-clicking the text. Is this possible?

I think it's possible because the same thing happens in I.E with that blue accelerator button thing.

Comment: @Trufa, I tried searching, but since I couldn't find something, that's all I could do..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't this be enough?

http://jsfiddle.net/cLY8r/

Here's the code if you don't want to follow the link:

```
<div id="target">
  Double-click here
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#target').dblclick(function() {
  alert('Handler for .dblclick() called.');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Trufa, this combined with @James' document.selection will get me exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the double clicky thing.

But in IE i believe it is `document.selection` i know in chrome it is `document.getSelection()`.

This returns you a selection range object.

some light reading:

- http://help.dottoro.com/ljfjepre.php 
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.getSelection

Answer (score 1):

A more robust solution that works in most browsers:

```
<div ondblclick="checkForSelectedText(this)">here is some text</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function checkForSelectedText() {
  var d = document;
  var t;

  // Modern browsers, including IE 6+
  if (d && d.selection && d.selection.createRange) {
    t = d.selection.createRange().text;
    alert('createRange supported\n' + t);

  // Others
  } else if (d.getSelection) {
    t = d.getSelection();
    alert('getSelection supported\n' + d.getSelection());
  }
  return t;
}
</script>
```

However will not work inside elements like textarea or input for most browsers. Here's a more general version:

```
<div ondblclick="checkForSelectedText(event)">here is some text
  <input value="and some inside an input">
  <textarea>Lorem ipsum in a textarea</textarea>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function checkForSelectedText(e) {
  var el = e.target || e.srcElement;
  var tagName = el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase();
  var t;
  var d = document;

  // Try DOM 2 Range - most browsers, including IE 6+
  if (d && d.selection && d.selection.createRange) {
    t = d.selection.createRange().text;
    alert('createRange supported\n' + t);

  // Otherwise try HTML5 - note that getSelection returns
  // a string with extra properties
  } else if (d.getSelection) {
    t = d.getSelection();
    alert('getSelection supported\n' + 
          '\n' + t);
  }

   // If didn't get any text, see if event was inside
   // inupt@type=text or textarea
  if (t == '') {

    if (tagName == 'textarea' || 
       (tagName == 'input' && el.type == 'text')) {
      t = el.value.substring(el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd)
      alert('Inside ' + tagName + '\n' + t);
    }
  }
  return t;
}
</script>
```

It may need a little more work for the case inside a form control, there should probably be tests for selectionStart and selectionEnd.

Comment: Ooh that worked really well, I've added selectionStart, selectionInProgress and selectionEnd - thanks a lot @RobG, much appreciated!